# absolute positioned div is not always fixed with bottom zero when i resize the window

Tags: css, css-position

i have a div positioned absolute inside another div. absolute positioned div has a background image and its bottom is 0. but when I resize the window it come out to the middle of the container div. it is not always fixed with bottom 0. how do i solve it??

```
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>

.img-container {
background: url("/images/laptop.jpg");
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
position: relative;
}
.wave {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 background: url("/images/wave.png");
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 143px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner div `.wave` is sticking to `bottom: 0`. (red bordered element is inner div with border just for demonstration)

[image]

This gap is created to maintain the aspect ratio of the image. If you are okay with stretching of the inner div background, set `background-size: 100% 100%;` (for inner div). It will stretch the image but will not create empty space which looks like `.wave` is not sticking to `bottom: 0;`